# How to create AutoScale Settings programmatically with C# for Windows Azure Web App using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring?

Tags: c#, azure, autoscaling

What Do I have:

```
var subscriptionId = "xxx";
var thumbprint = "xxx";

var certificate = GetCertificate(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser, thumbprint);

var autoscaleClient = new AutoscaleClient(new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, certificate));

var createParams = new AutoscaleSettingCreateOrUpdateParameters
{
    Setting = new AutoscaleSetting
    {
        Enabled = true,
        Profiles = new List<AutoscaleProfile>
        {
            new AutoscaleProfile
            {
                Capacity = new ScaleCapacity
                {
                    Default ="1",
                    Maximum="10",
                    Minimum="1"
                },
                Name = "anurag",
                Recurrence= new Recurrence
                {
                    Frequency=RecurrenceFrequency.Week,
                    Schedule = new RecurrentSchedule
                    {
                        Days = new List<string>{"Monday", "Thursday", "Friday"},
                        Hours = {7, 19},
                        Minutes=new List<int>{0},
                        TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
                    }
                },
                Rules=new List<ScaleRule>
                {
                    new ScaleRule
                    {
                        MetricTrigger =new MetricTrigger
                        {
                            MetricName="Test Metric",
                            MetricNamespace="",
                            MetricSource=
                            AutoscaleMetricSourceBuilder.BuildWebSiteMetricSource("???", "???"),
                            Operator=ComparisonOperationType.GreaterThan,
                            Threshold=2000,
                            Statistic=MetricStatisticType.Average,
                            TimeGrain=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                            TimeAggregation=TimeAggregationType.Average,
                            TimeWindow=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
                        },
                        ScaleAction = new ScaleAction
                        {
                            Direction = ScaleDirection.Increase,
                            Cooldown = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                            Type=ScaleType.ChangeCount,
                            Value = "4"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};


var resourceId = AutoscaleResourceIdBuilder.BuildWebSiteResourceId("???", "???");

var autoscaleResponse = autoscaleClient.Settings.CreateOrUpdate(resourceId, createParams);
```

I am confused about two API calls:

- `AutoscaleResourceIdBuilder.BuildWebSiteResourceId(string webspace, string serverFarmName)`
- `AutoscaleMetricSourceBuilder.BuildWebSiteMetricSource(string webspaceName, string websiteName)`

What is a webspace, server farm name, webspace name and web site name? Where Do I get them?